# Python: Setting an alarm outside of the main thread

Tags: python, signals, alarm

I know you can use `signal.alarm()` to schedule alarms in your main thread, but is there a way to do something like this in a thread that isn't your main thread, since these threads can't receive signals? I need to schedule something to happen 5 minutes in the future.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use signals rather than using something like the `Timer` class?

Comment: No, that's exactly what I was looking for though :) I just wasn't aware of any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Timer` instead of signals. Dealing with signals will open up lots of cans of worms, so you should avoid it whenever you can. In this case, it sounds like you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading.Event to notify your threads about events. Have a look at threading.Timer as well.

Comment: I'm using threading.Event right now, but I need to set an alarm to set() the event 5 minutes into the future somehow.